# Traefik unable to route to container with published ports

Tags: docker-swarm, traefik

I am attempting to run GitLab behind Traefik in a Docker Swarm. I am able to do so successfully so long as the GitLab container does not publish any ports. If I publish a port (i.e. for SSH), Traefik gives Gateway Timeout when attempting to route to it.

I have tried simply running a bare nginx server behind Traefik and if I publish some arbitrary port in the nginx container, Traefik is no longer able to route to it - so it's not an issue specific to the GitLab container.

Here's my functional docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  socat:
    image: alpine/socat
    command: tcp-listen:2375,fork,reuseaddr unix-connect:/var/run/docker.sock
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      - mgmt
    deploy:
      mode: global
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager

  traefik:
    image: traefik:latest
    configs:
      - source: traefik
        target: /etc/traefik.toml
    command: --etcd --etcd.endpoint=stateful_etcd-1:2379,stateful_etcd-2:2379,stateful_etcd-3:2379 --etcd.useAPIV3
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
      - 8080:8080
    networks:
      - mgmt
      - gitlab
      - stateful_etcd
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == worker
    depends_on:
      - socat

  gitlab:
    image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest'
    networks:
      - gitlab
    environment:
       GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
        external_url 'https://example.com'
        nginx['listen_port'] = 80
        nginx['listen_https'] = false
        gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 10022
        user['username'] = "root"
        user['group'] = "root"
    volumes:
      - test-gitlab-logs:/var/log/gitlab
      - test-gitlab-data:/var/opt/gitlab
    deploy:
      labels:
        traefik.docker.network: gitlab
        traefik.enable: "true"
        traefik.frontend.rule: "Host:example.com"
        traefik.port: 80
        traefik.protocol: http
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == worker

networks:
  mgmt:
  gitlab:
  stateful_etcd:
    external: true

configs:
  traefik:
    file: ./traefik.toml

volumes:
  test-gitlab-logs:
    external: true
  test-gitlab-data:
    external: true
```

and my traefik.toml:

```
debug = false

logLevel = "ERROR"
defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
  [entryPoints.https.tls]

[api]
entrypoint = "traefik"
dashboard= true
debug = true

[retry]

[docker]
endpoint = "tcp://socat:2375"
watch = true
swarmMode = true
exposedByDefault = false

[etcd]
endpoint = "stateful_etcd-1:2379,stateful_etcd-2:2379,stateful_etcd-3:2379"
watch = true
prefix = "/traefik"
useAPIV3 = true

[acme]
caServer = "https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
email = "me@me.com"
storage = "traefik/acme/account"
entryPoint = "https"
onHostRule = true
[acme.httpChallenge]
entryPoint = "http"
```

FYI, I have 3 etcd instances in another stack storing the config.

This setup works - I can go to https://example.com and access GitLab. However, if I add this to the GitLab container:

```
ports:
  - 10022:22
```

I get a Gateway Timeout when I go to https://example.com.

Is this expected behaviour? Is there a better way of publishing the SSH port of a container?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to solve the issue directly, but I was able to work around it by including an SSH proxy as a separate service:

```
ssh-proxy:
    image: tecnativa/tcp-proxy
    networks:
      - gitlab
    ports:
      - 10022:10022
    environment:
      LISTEN: ":10022"
      TALK: "gitlab:22"
```